# Bullet intersecting with enemy too many times (running through the update loop too often)

Tags: c++, intersection

```
for (int i = 0; i < playerBullets.size(); i++)
    {
        // Ship projectile hit enemy
        if (IntersectsWith(playerBullets[i].ReturnBoundingBox()) || IntersectsWith(playerBulletsTwo[i].ReturnBoundingBox()))
        {
            //Deal with enemies response to collision
            //Do damage
            Damage();

            if (ReturnHealth() <= 0)
            {
                this->mobsKilledCounter++;
                SetCurrentTexture(currentTextureKey);
            }
        }
    }
```

What happens is that the bullet hits the enemy and it runs the code and does damage (which is what I want), but then it runs through the code continuously after for the same bullet (like 1000 times a second), killing the enemy instantly. This code is in my Update loop which is why it's continuously going through it.

Anyone know how I can stop this? I tried booleans but it wasn't working too well because I am using a vector and multiple bullets/enemies.

Comment: If your intersection code is checking often enough, then wouldn't it make sense that a bullet could still be inside an enemy for a while? You should explicitly prevent the same bullet from hitting an enemy twice. A bullet can track the enemies it has hit, and if it's hitting the same one twice, don't deal damage. **Edit:** Or discard a bullet upon colliding with an enemy, unless it's some super penetrating bullet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need to see how you are handing your "bullet" objects, and maybe see the "Update loop", but I will throw some suggestions out there:

1 - Are these "bullets" destroyed on collision?  If the loop keeps running, and the bullets are still there, then they will be detected and deal damage every time your loop runs until they "exit" the object they are colliding with!

2 - Have you thought about putting a cool-down timer on how much damage a player can take per second?  Or a "bool has_dealt_damage_to_player" flag for your bullets?

Also, I have no idea what this is doing:
      this->mobsKilledCounter++;
Best of luck.  Maybe try a decent debugger?  What IDE are you working in?

Comment: Thanks alot! I never even thought of suggestion one. My bullets kept going on through. Suggestion 1 worked perfect.